# Rearrangment of time series data

Tags: r, sorting, time-series, subset

I am not good at "R" and not sure how to rearrange and subset time series data. Sorry, if this question sounds stupid.
I have a time series data of sea tide with four values per day (with missing values as well). Two values for high tide and two values for low tide. The time and date are given in the same column but in different rows. Now, I want to subset the data only for daytime (from 7:00 AM to 7:00 PM) not for night. Then I want to have data arranged in three columns only i) Date, ii) Time and iii) Tide. For Tide, I only need minimum and maximum values. Here is an example of the data and the desired arrangement of data. For each date, data is arranged in three rows similar to the example.

> 

```
1/1/2011    Low High    Low NA
Time    2:58 AM 9:38 AM 5:19 PM NA
Tide    1.2 m   2.2 m   0.6 m   NA
1/2/2011    High    Low High    Low
Time    2:07 AM 4:22 AM 10:19 AM    6:07 PM
Tide    1.4 m   1.3 m   2.3 m   0.4 m
```

> 

```
Date    Time    Tide
1/1/2011    17:19   0.6
1/1/2011    9:38    2.2
1/2/2011    2:07    1.4
1/2/2011    18:07   0.4
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting your data from? Knowing this may help ensure any solution is robust, i.e., will work with future data pulls.

Comment: @Woodstock, this data is from Abu Dahbi. The data is of 12 years so have lots of data to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input, `DF` is assumed to be as in the Note below.

`g`, the grouping vector, has one element per row of `DF` and is equal to `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...)`.  Alternate ways to compute `g` would be `n <- nrow(DF); g <- gl(n, 3, n)` or `n <- nrow(DF); g <- rep(1:3, n, n)`.

We then use `by` to split `DF` into groups and apply the indicated anonymous function to each group as defined by `g`.

The anonymous function combines the date and the times in the current group to create the date/times `dt` making use of the fact that the common date is `x[1,1]` and the times prior to being cleaned up are in `x[2,-1]`. 
 Using `dt` and the tides in `x[2, -1]` (prior to being cleaned up) it computes each of the three columns arranging them into a data frame. Then there is a commented out line which removes NA values.  If you want this uncomment it. Subset the data frame obtained so far to the 7am to 7pm time period and further take the two rows consisting of the min and max tide.  We sort that by time.

Finally `do.call("rbind", ...)` puts the groups together into one overall data frame.

No packages are used.

```
g <- cumsum(grepl("\\d", DF$V1))
Long <- do.call("rbind", by(DF, g, function(x) {
  dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(x[1,1], as.matrix(x[2, -1])), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
  X <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(dt),
                  Time = format(dt, "%H:%M"),
                  Tide = as.numeric(sub("m", "", as.matrix(x[3, -1]))),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # X <- na.omit(X)
  X <- subset(X, Time >= "07:00" & Time <= "19:00")
  X <- X[c(which.min(X$Tide), which.max(X$Tide)), ]
  X[order(X$Time), ]
}))
```

giving the following -- note that the third row in the question's output is not between 7am and 7pm so the output here necessarily differs.

```
> Long
          Date  Time Tide
1.2 2011-01-01 09:38  2.2
1.3 2011-01-01 17:19  0.6
2.3 2011-01-02 10:19  2.3
2.4 2011-01-02 18:07  0.4
```

**Note:** The input `DF` is assumed to be as follows in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "1/1/2011,Low,High,Low,NA
Time,2:58 AM,9:38 AM,5:19 PM,NA
Tide,1.2 m,2.2 m,0.6 m,NA
1/2/2011,High,Low,High,Low
Time,2:07 AM,4:22 AM,10:19 AM,6:07 PM
Tide,1.4 m,1.3 m,2.3 m,0.4 m"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow along with what you did. Cutting and pasting your code, my output has the second row as `1.3 2011-01-02 17:19  0.6` --> note this is Jan 2, not Jan 1 ... did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: Start a fresh session of R, copy and paste the code in the Note to generate the input and then copy and paste the code in the answer itself to get the result.  That should match the result shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not too long, this endeavour would be simpler to do in a spreadsheet simply by mapping cells and filtering. But one way to do it in R with zoo and tidyverse is the following:

Assuming that the original dataframes have their columns named as C1:C5

```
        C1      C2      C3       C4      C5
     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
1 1/1/2010     Low    High      Low    <NA>
2     Time 2:58 AM 9:38 AM  5:19 PM    <NA>
3     Tide     1.2     2.2      0.6    <NA>
4 1/2/2011    High     Low     High     Low
5     Time 2:07 AM 4:22 AM 10:19 AM 6:07 PM
6     Tide     1.4     1.3      2.3     0.4

DF <- DF %>% 
        mutate(Date = as.Date(gsub("Tide|Time","", C1), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
DF <- DF %>% 
        mutate(Date = na.locf(DF$Date, na.rm = TRUE),
                        C1 = gsub("[[:digit:]]|\\/", "", C1),
                        Type = if_else(nchar(C1) == 0, "TideType", C1)) %>% 
              select(Date, Type, C2:C5) %>% 
              gather(oColumn, Value, -c(Date, Type)) %>%
              spread(key = Type, value = Value) %>% 
              select(Date, Time, Tide) %>%
              filter(complete.cases(.))
DF <- DF %>% 
         mutate(Time = ymd_hm(paste(DF$Date, DF$Time, sep = " ")),
                Tide = as.numeric(Tide))
DF <- DF %>% 
         mutate(DayNight = (DF$Time) %within% 
          interval(as.POSIXlt(DF$Date) + (7*60*60), as.POSIXlt(DF$Date) + (19*60*60))) %>% 
        filter(DayNight == TRUE) %>%
        select(-DayNight) ) %>%
        group_by(Date) %>%
        filter(Tide == max(Tide) | min(Tide))

DF
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: Date [2]

        Date                Time  Tide
      <date>              <dttm> <dbl>
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-01 09:38:00   2.2
2 2010-01-01 2010-01-01 17:19:00   0.6
3 2011-02-01 2011-02-01 10:19:00   2.3
4 2011-02-01 2011-02-01 18:07:00   0.4
```

Note that "Date" is a Date type of Object and "Time" is a Posixct type of Date-Time  Object. You might want to convert "Time" into a vector of minutes.